# Jump to iframe once it loads

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, scroll

Im looking for my webpage to jump to an iframe when someone click. I've found one solution which works pretty well which is this: http://jsfiddle.net/RGjCL/4/

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="IFrameScroll('http://www.asdf.com')">Class Name</a>
    </li>
 </ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function IFrameScroll(link){
        window.myIframe.location=link;
        window.location.hash='myIframe'
    }
</script>
<IFRAME id = "myframe"  onload = "setIframeHeight( this.id )" name="myIframe">
```

I've tried on my web and it partially works except for the fact it scrolls to the iframe before it loads so it doesn't goes that far to the bottom because once the iframe its loaded the page fully extends.

The web in question is the following: http://www.clavederock.com.ar - 
The links are under the tabs "Quienes Somos" "Programacion" and "Archivo".

I hope i made myself clear so you can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I saw your website's code and I understand what you want. The iframe is empty the first time, so you can remove the onload of it and *bind* it on first click (this will prevent changing the hash the first time), then try the 3rd edit of my answer.

Comment: it still isn't working. The third edit didn't even jump to the iframe. I noticed the following: on the second edit there is this `this will ensure the height will be updated after the load setIframeHeight('myIframe');` That its the problem. The rest was doing fine. What i need is to resize before loading and the jump to it: resize-load-jump. What do you think?

Comment: BTW i went back to the second option so you can see: http://clavederock.com.ar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving `window.location.hash='myIframe'` from the function `IFrameScroll()` to `setIFrameHeight()`, so you'll change the hash once the iframe have the desired size.

EDIT #3:

Since you need to wait until iframe is loaded in order to resize it and `window.location.hash` doesn't works the second time in chrome, you can try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function IFrameScroll(link){

        window.myIframe.onload = function() {
            // this will ensure that the height will be updated after load
            setIframeHeight('myIframe');
            // This works on FF and IE, and let users to bookmark
            window.location.hash='myIframe';
            // and this will allow it to scroll the second time for chrome
            document.getElementById('myIframe').scrollIntoView(true);
        }

        window.myIframe.location=link;

    }
</script>
```

I really hope this solve your problem :)

Comment: Hey!! Thanks for your help. I tryed your first suggestion (the one before the EDIT) and it worked great on firefox and IE9. It didn't work on chrome though.. I'll try the other option. Any suggestion?

Comment: It is weird that it didn't work in chrome. What exactly didn't work?

Comment: I've found that the chrome problem comes from the IFrameScroll function. It works only the first time one clicks and then it doesn't work any more.

Comment: I actually need for the iframe to be loaded to resize it. I tried your second option and my iframe doesn't resizes before showing content so it doesn't work

Comment: I think the problem in chrome is that it doesn't scrolls when you try to set the hash without changing it: the second time you click the link the hash doesn't change, so chrome doesn't scroll down.

Comment: ohh i see.. that has to be happening then. Any suggestion on how to solve that?

Comment: Here's the thing: I've been cheking on my first option (the first you suggested) and it works pretty well except for the fact that when i load the page it hashes for the iframe directly. That is, when i enter http://clavederock.com.ar it goes to http://clavederock.com.ar#myIframe instead. See it for yourself (And my web icon disappears ¿?)

Comment: I got it! :-) sorry, my first intent won't work for you: `setIframeHeight` is being executed when the iframe is loaded the first time too, with original url, and that is why `clavederock.com.ar` changes to `clavederock.com.ar#myIframe` on first load. Try with my second intent, so it scrolls only when user clicks.

Comment: i've tryed your second edit.. and it fails to resize the iframe. would you mind taking a look? http://clavederock.com.ar - i may be doing something wrong :s

Comment: it still isn't working. The third edit didn't even jump to the iframe. I noticed the following: on the second edit there is this :`this will ensure the height will be updated after the load setIframeHeight('myIframe');` That its the problem. The rest was doing fine. What i need is to resize before loading and the jump to it: resize-load-jump. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of jumping to the iframe, you could make a smooth scroll.  This would give a little more time for the iframe to load after the link has been clicked.

Alternatively and probably more effectively, you could load the iframe with the rest of the page but make it invisible. Then you just need to show it when the user clicks the link

```
//load the page with the iframe hidden
//in css
#myIframe { visibility: hidden; }
//use jquery to make it visible when the user clicks the link
//you could do this with javascript if you don't want to import jQuery, but I find jQuery easier
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myAnchorTagId').click(
        function() {
            $('myIframe').css('visibiliy', 'visible')
        }
    )
});
```